# How can i use two selectors for one event

Tags: jquery

I'm newbie at JQuery, and I am building a Webpage, I'm putting multiple elements visible, but when a event is called. Since I did it separated, i would like to put my code smaller putting the selectors together.

Here my code, i would like to merge the selectors:

```
$(".m-info-lnk").find("li:nth-child(-n+4)").css("visibility", "visible");
$(".m-info-lnk").find("li:nth-child(4) a img").css("visibility","visible");
```

How can o do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a comma `,` to separate multiple selectors:

```
$(".m-info-lnk").find("li:nth-child(-n+4), li:nth-child(4) a img").css("visibility", "visible");
```

**Simplified example:** http://jsfiddle.net/cm4kjt3u/